# How to sort part of values in list?

Tags: python

I want to sort the value which startswith `chapter`  in list, but I have no idea to implement this.

**my list**

```
["prologue", "chapter 1", "chapter 3", "chapter 2", "sick", "chapter 5", "chapter 4"]
```

**expected**

```
["prologue", "chapter 1", "chapter 2", "chapter 3", "sick", "chapter 4", "chapter 5"]
```

**Edited**

> What should the output look like if instead of 'chapter 2' you had 'chapter 22' in the same position in the list? – Lancelot du Lac

I don't have this problem yet. But if so, I will want this one.

```
['prologue', 'chapter 1', 'chapter 3', 'sick', 'chapter 4', 'chapter 5', 'chapter 22']
```

use `@mosc9575` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72232454/17743620)
but change the `sorted()` to `natsorted()` [module](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

The result will be

```
['prologue', 'chapter 1', 'chapter 3', 'chapter 4', 'sick', 'chapter 5', 'chapter 22']
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: What should the output look like if instead of 'chapter 2' you had 'chapter 22' in the same position in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, but I am sure there are a lot more.

```
my_list = ["prologue", "chapter 1", "chapter 3", "chapter 2", "sick", "chapter 5", "chapter 4"]
to_sort = []
to_sort_index = []
for i, item  in enumerate(my_list):
    if item.startswith('chapter'):
        to_sort.append(item)
        to_sort_index.append(i)
for i, item in zip(to_sort_index, sorted(to_sort)):
    my_list [i] = item
```

Result:

```
['prologue',
 'chapter 1',
 'chapter 2',
 'chapter 3',
 'sick',
 'chapter 4',
 'chapter 5']
```